# Difference between \( \) and $ $

Tags: math-mode

I read discussion about diferences between `\[ \]` and `$$ $$`; but nothing or very little about `\( \)` and `$ $`. There are a differences?

Comment: Is necessary delete my question?

Comment: I don't think so. It'll be closed.